# Setup bank-compatible redirect with IIS and MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis

We have an MVC application which runs with IIS 8 on a Windows Server 2012 R2. You can call the application with https://host/, https://host/Login, https://host/Whatever Everything's fine.

This application has been deployed onto a machine of a bank. There are some scheduled jobs running to check if some system parameters are set properly. One of these checks verifies that every application in the IIS has a redirect to https. Originally they've set the redirect to https://host/Login which produced links like https://host/Login/User, https://host/Login/Logs and so on.

So they tried to set the redirect to https://host/ This caused a redirect loop.

For now they've disabled the check. But it is just a matter of days till some admin is tired of the "misconfigured" system notification and reactivates the redirect.

I need a solution which includes the `<httpRedirect>` in `<system.webServer>`. Any ideas? Maybe with an additional set of rewrite rules? Or even some code changes (although I'd like to avoid that)?

The current setting is `<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://localhost/" exactDestination="false" childOnly="true" />`

Best regards,
   Carsten

Answer (score 0):

Just add `RequireHttpsAttribute` to your global filters:

**App_Start/FilterConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nope, did not do the trick. Neither https://localhost/ nor https://localhost/Logs work. Both are redirected 120 times...

Comment: Then you have something else conflicting with the redirect. Importantly, if you use the global filter, you should not *also* be doing a URL rewrite.

Comment: I do not have any other redirects, other than the `<httpRedirect>` in the `Web.config`. Any suggestions what might cause the trouble?